# Loading a data efficiently in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the data of the following form in a text file

```
Userid Gameid Count
Jason  1      2
Jason  2      10
Jason  4      20
Mark   1      2
Mark   2      10
................
.................
```

There are a total of 81 Gameids and I have around 2 million distinct users.

What I want is to read this text file and create a sparse matrix of the form

```
      Column 1 2  3 4  5 6 .
Row1  Jason  2 10   20
Row2  Mark   2 10
```

Now I can load this text file in matlab and read the users one by one, reading their count and initializing the sparse array. I have tried this, it takes 1 second to initialize the row of one user. So for a total of 2 million users, it will take me a lot of time.

what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Here is my code

```
data = sparse(10000000, num_games);
loc = 1;

for f=1:length(files)
  file = files(f).name;

  fid = fopen(file,'r');

  s = textscan(fid,'%s%d%d');

  count = (s(:,2));
  count = count{1};
  position = (s(:,3));
  position = position{1};

  A=s{:,1};
  A=cellstr(A);

  users = unique(A);

  for aa = 1:length(Users)
      a = strfind(A, char(Users(aa)));
      ix=cellfun('isempty',a);
      index = find(ix==0);
      data(loc,position(index,:)) = count(index,:);
      loc = loc + 1;
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want your sparse matrix to look like. Do you want it to contain both values *and* player name strings? Alternatively, do you want to create a sparse matrix for each player?

Answer (score 2):

- Avoid the inner loop by using`unique` once more for `GameID`.
- Store the user names, because in your original code you can't tell which name - relates to each row. The same thing for game IDs.
- Make sure to close the file after opening it.
- `sparse` matrix does not support `'int32'` you need to store your data as `double`.

---

```
% Place holders for Count
Rows = [];
Cols = [];

for f = 1:length(files)
    % Read the data into 's'
    fid = fopen(files(f).name,'r');
    s = textscan(fid,'%s%f%f');
    fclose(fid);

    % Spread the data
    [U, G, Count{f}] = s{:};

    [Users{f},~, r] = unique(U); % Unique user names
    [GameIDs{f},~,c] = unique(G); % Unique GameIDs

    Rows = [Rows; r + max([Rows; 0])];
    Cols = [Cols; c + max([Cols; 0])];
end

% Convert to linear vectors
Count = cell2mat(Count');
Users = reshape([Users{:}], [], 1);
GameIDs = cell2mat(GameIDs');

% Create the sparse matrix
Data = sparse(Rows, Cols, Count, length(Users), length(GameIDs), length(Count));
```

The `Users` will contain be the **Row header** (user names) and `GameIDs` the **Column header**.